# Android Room with Jetpack Compose - Update LiveData after add a item in another activity

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I'm adding a new contact on the NewContactActivity and after complete inserts on the DB and closes the activity but this not update the contacts list

MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                val contatoViewModel: ContatoViewModel = viewModel(factory = ContatoViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current.applicationContext as Application))
                val contatos = contatoViewModel.readAllData.observeAsState(listOf()).value
                val novoContatoLaunch = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
                    run {
                        when(it.resultCode) {
                            RESULT_OK -> {
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Contato Salvo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                //TODO I need to update the contatos here
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                MainView(contatos) {
                    novoContatoLaunch.launch(Intent(this@MainActivity, NovoContatoActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

NewContactActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                val contatoViewModel: ContatoViewModel = viewModel(factory = ContatoViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current.applicationContext as Application))

                NovoContatoView {
                    contatoViewModel.addContato(it)
                    setResult(RESULT_OK)
                    finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer will be inside your `ContatoViewModel`. If you're using `LiveData` via room library this should update automatically after the change in database. If not, just call some method in `ContatoViewModel` that will read changes from the database and update the underlying live data